# How to convert sql query to query builder typeorm format

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

1: This is sql query

```
INSERT INTO  allocation (
          effort, "startDate", "endDate", "employeeId", "projectId"
        ) 
        SELECT Distinct
          request_allocation_detail.effort, 
          request_allocation_detail."startDate", 
          request_allocation_detail."endDate", 
          request_allocation_detail."employeeId", 
          request_allocation."projectId"
        From 
          public.request_allocation 
          inner join public.request_allocation_detail ON request_allocation_detail."requestAllocationId" = request_allocation.id 
        where 
          request_allocation_detail.id = '${currentRequestDetailId}'
```

2: this is query builder using typeorm but it not work:

=>Create query builder and try to insert into using select with typeorm

```
    const db= this.allocationRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('allocation')
      .insert()
      .into('allocation')
      .values(['effort', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'employeeId', 'projectId'])
      .select([
        'request_allocation_detail.effort',
        'request_allocation_detail."startDate"',
        'request_allocation_detail."endDate"',
        'request_allocation_detail."employeeId"',
        'request_allocation."projectId"',
      ])
      .distinct()
      .from('request_allocation', 'request_allocation')
      .innerJoinAndSelect(
        'request_allocation_detail',
        'request_allocation_detail',
        'request_allocation_detail.id = request_allocation.id'
      )
      .where('request_allocation_detail.id = :id', {
        id: currentRequestDetailId,
      });
```

Please help me how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

First i separate sql query to 2 phase: select and insert:
Second: i write querybuilder with typeorm to command select:

```
const (*) [subQuery, params] = this.createQueryBuilder(
      'request_allocation_detail'
    )
      .innerJoin(
        'request_allocation',
        'request_allocation',
        'request_allocation_detail."requestAllocationId" = request_allocation.id'
      )
      .where('request_allocation_detail.id = :id', {
        id: currentRequestDetailId,
      })
      .select([
        'request_allocation_detail.effort',
        'request_allocation_detail.startDate',
        'request_allocation_detail.endDate',
        'request_allocation_detail."employeeId"',
        'request_allocation."projectId"',
      ])
      .getQueryAndParameters();
```

Next i return with command insert into with command query in typeorm:

```
return this.query(
      `
    INSERT INTO  allocation (here is column i need to add data from *)${subQuery}`,
      params
    );
```